# XPath query for Google Sheets ImportXML to get YouTube video URL from page

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the video URL for the YT video on [this page](http://lb.cineklik.com/movie/war_dogs/trailer) into Google sheets through the ImportXML function but I can't seem to find the right XPath query!

I usually "Copy XPath" from Inspect Element in Chrome, but for some reason it isn't working this time -_-

Here's what I get from "copy xpath" I'll spare you the 3100 variations I tried:

```
//*[@id='player_uid_64232849_1']/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[1]
//*[@id='content']/div[3]/iframe
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the xpath for iframe with video:

`//div[@id = 'content']//iframe`

You can extract the url by getting `src` attribute

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! :D

Comment: I'd love to but I'm new here and still can't upvote before I reach 15 reputation :$

Answer (score 1):

You could also just simplify your xpath to `//iframe/@src`